# How to email URL

Tags: iphone, url

How to email URL from iphone app which contains "&" in it.
This is sample URL

```
http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=facebook&oq=facebook&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...0l0l0l1620716l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0.frgbld.&mvs=0
```

Comment: Because & is taken as special character in objective c, you have to validate the URL string before mailing it

Comment: Thanx Sree for reply. which kind of validation should i do ?

Comment: Use string encoding methods...

Comment: Thanx Chandan for reply i have tried [url stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] encoding but it will consider link upto first "&". in above url it is emailing only "http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        CFStringRef escaped = 
        CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault,
                                                (CFStringRef)theURL,
                                                NULL,
                                                (CFStringRef)@"!*'();:@&=+$,/?%#[]",
                                                kCFStringEncodingUTF8);

                    NSString* useit = (NSString*)escaped;
```

don't forget to release CGStringRef

Answer (score 0):

try this: in MFMailComposure iN Email Function in App

```
-(void)displayComposerSheet
{
MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[picker setSubject:@"My URL!"];

// Set up recipients
NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"xyz@abc.com"];
NSString *emailBody = @"http://www.google.co.in/search?hl=en&safe=active&q=facebook&oq=facebook&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&gs_l=mobile-gws-serp.3...0l0l0l1620716l0l0l0l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0.frgbld.&mvs=0";
[picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

[self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
[picker release];
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
message.hidden = NO;

switch (result)
{
case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
message.text = @" Message canceled";
break;
case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
message.text = @"Message saved";
break;
case MFMailComposeResultSent:
message.text = @"Message sent";
break;
case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
message.text = @"Message failed";
break;
default:
message.text = @"Message not sent";
break;
}
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```